# piezoelectric sensor

Tags: piezo-buzzer

i am working on piezoelectrics sensors.now after converting the voltage from ac to dc i need to store it in a btttery so that i can further use it as any charging device (THATS later part).Now i need an idea ,that the voltage  through
these plates is discontinuous,my ques is that is there any problem in charging a battery with discontinuous voltage ,if no then its ok ,but if there is a problem ,what can i do to make voltage continuous, or any suggestion u guys have .

thankyou

Comment: The energy you are getting from piezo is *tiny*. I don't think it can be used to charge anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some kind of energy harvesting circuit. For example [this one.](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3588-1)